# How to POST 50k+ id's to server with AJAX in MVC 5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, url, post, asp.net-mvc-5

This is how I make my post request. `data` contains an array of `selectedIds` and it's possible with the `traditional` property. The problem is that if I need to POST 200 selectedIds the URL is to long and it breaks. What is best pratice to solve this situation? Only idea I can think of is looping my ids and POST'ing them in smaller chunks, but don't know the downsides or there is a more standard way of doing this?

`POST:`

```
var addToBuffer = function(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        traditional: true,
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        data: data
    });
},
```

`Url ( there is 200+ selectedIds ):`

http://localhost/foo/Buffer/AddToComputerAndDevicesBuffer?selectedIds=2639&selectedIds=5386&selectedIds=3225&selectedIds=6791&selectedIds=3231&selectedIds=357 ...

`Error message:`

"HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found"

"The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long."

"Most likely causes:"
 - "Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the query string is too long."

"Things you can try:"
- "Verify the configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits@maxQueryString setting in the applicationhost.config or web.config file."

**Update 1:**

Just realized just before posting this question, that I am not POST'ing but using GET, and **it works** with 200 ids, when I used:

```
var addToBuffer = function(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        data: data
    });
},
```

But that quickly raises another question, will this still works when I scale up to 10k+ or even 1M+? Do I get a timeout or am I DDos'ing my own server? Am I back to the loop with smaller chunks solution, or does anyone have any good advises how they solved this before? Thanks.

Comment: 1 million will be no problem at all. There is no specific size limit for posts. It generally limited by the web server

Comment: 1MB? Do you mean 1.000.000 like me?

Comment: Sorry, clarified in comment - but it might take a long time :)

Comment: Thinking about the scaling issue.. I think at this point the size limit would't be the first problem i will run into, but rather all the work that im planning do to with the ids on the server. That the action in it self would struggle before I reach problems with the ids size.

Comment: In any case, why would you ever need to post that much data?

Comment: I need to link two units together. For that I first selected all the units of one kind, and pass the id's to the server to put in a database table. Next you will select all the other units in the client and send the id's to the server to  "link" them together. 
I have just changed my tables to `server-side processing` so they now potential can contain 5.000.000 rows, hence a new huge amount of id's.
So I now have no trouble with scaling in the tables, but I now have to think about the impact my features has after this change. And what I might have to rewrite.